# PDDL Predicate name must be a string

Tags: pddl

I am trying to solve a planning assignment with pddl and i wrote the following domain

```
 (define (domain Monster)
    (:requirements :strips)
    (:predicates (player ?p) (location ?x) (monster ?m) (treasure ?tr) (trap ?tp) (weapon ?w) (flyer ?f) ;entities 
             (playerat ?player ?location) (monsterat ?monster ?location) (trapat ?trap ?location) (treasureat ?trasure ?location) (weaponat ?weapon ?location) (flyerat ?flyer ?location); relations 
             (gameOver ?p) (holdsw ?p) (holdsf ?p) (holdst ?p) (go ?A ?B) (close ?A ?B)
    )

    (:action Move  ;Move from location A to location B
        :parameters (?P ?A ?B ?M) ; P->Player A->Location_1 B->Location_2  
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?A) (location ?B) (monster ?M) (playerat ?P ?A) (go ?A ?B) (not(monsterat ?M ?B)) )
        :effect (and(playerat ?P ?B) (not(playerat ?P ?A)) )
    )

    (:action PickWeapon ; picking up weapon
        :parameters (?P ?L ?W) ;P->player L->location W->Weapon
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (weapon ?W) (playerat ?P ?L) (weaponat ?W ?L)  )
        :effect (and(holdsw ?P) (not(weaponat ?W ?L)))
    )
    
    (:action PickFlyer ;picking up flyer
        :parameters (?P ?L ?F) ;P->player L->location F->flyer 
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (flyer ?F) (playerat ?P ?L) (flyerat ?F ?L)   )
        :effect (and(holdsf ?P) (not(flyerat ?F ?L)) )
    )
    
    (:action PickTreasure ;picking up treasure
        :parameters (?P ?L ?T) ;P->player L->location T->treasure
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (treasure ?T) (playerat ?P ?L) (treasureat ?T ?L)   )
        :effect (and(holdst ?P) (not(treasureat ?T ?L)) )
    )
    
    (:action PlayerKilled ;player killed
        :parameters (?P ?L ?M) ;P->player L->location M->monster
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (monster ?M) (playerat ?P ?L) (monsterat ?M ?L) (not(holdsw ?P)) (not(holdsf ?P)) )
        :effect (and(gameOver ?P) (not(playerat ?P ?L)) ); Game Over
    )
    
    (:action PlayerTraped ;Player traped 
        :parameters (?P ?L ?TR) ;P->player L->location TR->trap
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (trap ?TR) (playerat ?P ?L) (trapat ?TR ?L) (not(holdsf ?P)) )
        :effect (and(gameOver ?P) (not(playerat ?P ?L)) )
    )
    
    (:action Kill ;Killing Monster
        :parameters (?P ?A ?M ?B) ;P->player L->location M->monster 
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?B) (location ?A) (monster ?M) (playerat ?P ?A) (monsterat ?M ?B) (holdsw ?P) (close ?A ?B) (go ?A ?B) )
        :effect (and(playerat ?P ?B) (not(monsterat ?M ?B)) (not(holdsw ?P)) )
    )

    (:action FlyOverMonster
        :parameters (?P ?F ?L ?A ?M) ;P->player L->location F->flyer M->monster
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (location ?A) (monster ?M) (playerat ?P ?A) (monsterat ?M ?L) (holdsf ?P) (close ?A ?L) (go ?A ?L) )
        :effect (and(playerat ?P ?L) (not(holdsf ?P)) )
    )
    
    (:action FlyOverTrap
        :parameters (?P ?F ?L ?A ?TR) ;P->player L->location F->flyer TR->trap
        :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (location ?A) (trap ?TR) (playerat ?P ?A) (trapat ?TR ?L) (holdsf ?P) (close ?A ?L) (go ?A ?L) )
        :effect (and(playerat ?P ?L) (not(holdsf ?P)) )
    )
    
)
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1O1w.png)
i defined the problem to be planned as follows

```
(define (problem Monster2)
(:domain Monster)

(:objects a b c d e f g h i pl mo tp fl tr wp
)

(:init
    (location a) (location b) (location c) (location d) (location e) (location f) (location g) (location h) (location i)
    (player pl) (monster mo) (trap tp) (flyer fl) (treasure tr) (weapon wp)
    (go a b) (go b a) (go b c) (go c b) (go c d) (go d c) (go a e) (go e b) (go e f) (go f d) (go e g) (go e h) (go h e) (go h i) (go i h)
    (close b c) (close c d) (close e f)
    (playerat pl a) (monsterat mo c) (treasureat tr d) (trapat tp f) (weaponat wp h) (flyerat fl i)
)

(:goal (and
            (holdst pl)
            (playerat pl a)
        )
)
```

)

Trying to solve the problem i Changed my code but now I am facing another problem. The agent after killing the monster does not go to the next room but he returns back and then jambs to d room collects the treasure and stay at d. The strange thing is that the planer says that the agent is now at room c and in next state it says he is at room b.

Planner result
[Planer Kill Monster agent at room c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ivA.png)

Planner result
[Planner Move next supposed to be room d and it says room b state which is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkRdC.png)

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming, Dimitrios. For us to help you, you should always say exactly which command you ran on your PDDL to produce the error, and copy the exact error output in your question.

Comment: Victor thank you very much for you help. As you can see trying to solve the problem I changed my code as above. But now I am facing another problem. The agent is supposed to go through a trap and a monster, kill the monster fly over trap collect the treasure and return to start point. The planner now give me a plan but although the agent kill the monster then return to previous state and then jambs to room where treasure is located, collects it and stay there which is not what he was supposed to do. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I also added three screen shots.

Comment: Ok, but now your question is different. Please note that StackOverflow is not a forum. It seeks to give clear answers to clear questions, across contexts.
In your case, where you try to learn how to do design a problem, you should rather seek live assistance on the planning community's Slack.

However, looking at your PDDL, I do not understand how your current goal leads to your current plan. I think the information you provided is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several mistakes in the PDDL file. I tested it with FF.

In the domain file you missed some AND and few parenthesis in different action definitions, e.g.

```
(:action Kill
    :parameters (?P ?L ?M ?A) ;P->player L->location M->monster
    :precondition (and(player ?P) (location ?L) (location ?A) (monster ?M) (atp ?P ?A) (atm ?M ?L) (holdsw ?P ?W) (close ?A ?L) )
    :effect (and (not(atm ?M ?L)) (not(holdsw ?P ?W)) (atp ?P ?L))
)
```

Then you forgot to declare some predicates used in domain definition, e.g. at1...at6, located

Then in actions *FlyOverMonster* and *FlyOverTrap* you forgot to declare variable ?A, variable ?W in actions *Kill* and *PlayerKilled*.

In action  *PlayerKilled* you have a predicate hold that doesn't appear anywhere else.

I don't continue, but I hope that the corrections are clear. Then, the planner should point out the kind of error it encounters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I do appreciate it because I am learning from your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check your predicates name, I am not sure numbers are supported in their names, and in their parameter names.
In your problem, I can see occurrences of `at1`, `at2`, etc... These predicates are named strangely, and I am suspicious it is meant to work.
Moreover, they are not declared in your domain.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do appreciate it. Trying to solve one problem created another. I did not know if numbers are supported and i tried to create relations between locations and objects.

Comment: At this point you do not really have one question we can answer to. You are rather to figure out how to code at all in PDDL. Check the PDDL wiki, that lists learning resources : https://planning.wiki/. If you still need the live help of someone, try the community's Slack: https://theplanningcommunity.slack.com, or come back here with more narrowed down questions.